# Pointer to string changes its value unexpectedly

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I have noted that, when writing a string in an array allocated with `malloc()`, its value changes. To be clear, here is the code that replicates this "error":

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N (20)

int main()
{
   char * a_p;
   a_p = malloc( N * sizeof(char));
   printf(" * 01 pointer -> %p\n", a_p);
   a_p = "something";
   printf(" * 02 pointer -> %p\n", a_p);
   printf("-- TEST --\n");
   return 0;

}
```

When executing, the output is:

```
 * 01 pointer -> 0x1332010
 * 02 pointer -> 0x4006b9
-- TEST --
```

While I was expecting the same value because I am not changing where the pointer points (at least not directly). This causes problem when using `free()`. What is happening under the wood? What am I missing? How to do these things the right way?

Comment: "I am not changing where the pointer points", you are changing the pointer value... so yes you are changing where "the pointer points"

Comment: I haven't written C code in years but I think that is the way strings work. You got a pointer to the string, "something"'s,  address in memory which is different than address of the memory you malloc'ed

Comment: this is the same problem I had here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955927/kfree-error-when-used-with-pointer ). isn't it?

Comment: You should add some error handling to your code! Example: check if `malloc()` returned `NULL`, it means `malloc()` failed to allocate memory and you might want to abort.

Comment: @Ronan, You are right, this was written just to replicate the error and explain it to the community avoiding "verbose"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your problem

You are allocating memory for your pointer with `malloc()` but then you assign your pointer variable to something else (`"something"`, which has its own address), instead of filling the newly-allocated pointer.

### Solution

You should use the `strdup()` function that allocates memory and copies a string at the allocated memory:

```
a_p = strdup("something");
```

Or the `strcpy()` function, that takes a `malloc()`'d pointer and a string to copy in the pointed memory:

```
a_p = malloc(N * sizeof(char));
strcpy(a_p, "something");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the pointer directly. This statement

```
a_p = "something";
```

is equivalent to

```
a_p = &"something"[0];
```

String literals have types of character arrays. For example the string literal `"something"` has type `char[10]`.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals.78) **The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence.** For character string literals,
>   the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the
>   individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence...

Used in expressions arrays with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So after this statement

```
a_p = "something";
```

the pointer points to the first character of the string literal with the static storage duration.

I think you mean

```
strcpy( a_p, "something" );
```

That is you wanted to copy the string literal in the dynamically allocated memory.

Take into account that if even you'll write the following code

```
char *p1 = "string";
char *p2 = "string";
```

then it is not necessary that `p1` is equal to `p2` because depending on compiler options the compiler can place these two identical string literals in different memory extents.

So the if statement

```
if ( p1 == p2 )
```

can yield either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Well the literal string are basically arrays and *it decayed into pointer* to the first element when you assigned it to `a_p`. That address is being printed.

And as you dont keep the address of the allocated memory you are having *memory leak*.

Also you cant use it in `free` and that gives enough hint that it is not allocated dynamically . From standard

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function**, or
>   if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   **behavior is undefined.**

Well this explains why you faced problem when trying to `free` memory you haven't allocated.

Again to have something like copying you need to use `strcpy` or `strncpy` or `strdup`(POSIX compliant).

For more information check this **[link](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6)**. Standard says it explicitly how it is considered as array in translation steps.

Especially this part - ( Decayed pointer is of type `char*` that's why)

> <sup>For character string literals, the array elements have type
>   `char`, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte
>   character sequence.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The string literal `"something"` represents a null-terminated series of characters that live in some read-only region (most likely `.text` if you build/link/run on a GNU/Linux system).

Initially, `a_p` points to somewhere in the memory region within which `malloc` is allocating buffers. You can freely write to the location to which `a_p` points, `free()` it, etc. When you perform the assignment `a_p = "something";`, you are not writing characters to the location to which `a_p` points, but rather changing that pointer to point to the beginning of that string. Now, you're pointing into (read-only) memory that wasn't allocated by `malloc` so its corresponding `free` function isn't able to do anything meaningful.

Use `strcpy` (or better yet for safety, `strncpy`) instead to copy characters to the destination, `a_p`.